# I cannot start any program from PythonStdioGames and get an error, how can I prevent this?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I am relatively new to Python and programming in general and currently learning Python with the book "Automate the boring stuff with Python" by Al Sweigart. As recommended in the book, I wanted to do some programming exercises myself by looking into the module gamesbyexample (https://github.com/asweigart/pythonstdiogames/).

However, whenever I start one of the games I get the following error message in the Terminal:

```
AdminisatorsMBP:~ simon$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/gamesbyexample/__crashdetector__.py 0.1.5 /Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/gamesbyexample/alphabetizequiz.py
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/gamesbyexample/__crashdetector__.py", line 16
    except KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using multiple versions of python, 3.7.7 and 3.8.2, but with both versions, the same message comes up.

How could I get this running properly?

Comment: Did you download the scripts directly from Github, or did they come from elsewhere? In the file `_crashreporter.py` there is a recent change (April 2 2020) that reads "Missed this syntax error in the crash detector somehow." Perhaps you have an older version?

Answer (score -1):

This is a syntax error, which means that you're probably missing something in the code that the compiler was expecting to be there. 
If you could please also post the code, we could see what the problem is.